# How to get the type of a variable declared in a using statement in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using Rolsyn, to try and find all the places within a solution a 'Save' method is called on an ISession object. This is my current solution:

```
if (call.Expression.ToString().Contains("Save"))
{
   var innerExpression = call.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;

      if (innerExpression != null)
      {
         if (model.GetTypeInfo(innerExpression.Expression).Type.Name.Equals("ISession"))
         {
            //Do some work.
         }
      }
}
```

This works fine for normal scenarios. However is the ISession object is declared within a using-statement, like in the example below. The GetTypeInfo method on the SemaniticModel, brings back an 'ErrorType ?'.

```
using (var session = SessionHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
   session.Save(entityObject);
}
```

Is there anyway to do this? I've inspected the code in the Visual Studio Syntax Visualiser and the type information is available there, which makes me think it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the type returned is an error type, its because your solution has unresolved references, and so can't find that type. You need to tell roslyn to include these references for the solution.

This is done by creating [MetadataReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.metadatareference?view=roslyn-dotnet) and adding them to a project:

Pseudo code:

```
MetadataReference assemblyReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"c:\path\to\some.dll");

var solutionPath = @"c:\path\to\my.sln";
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    var referencedProject = project.AddMetadataReference(assemblyReference);
    var compilation = referencedProject.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
}
```